# Opencart 2.x and Jquery UI Dialog makes "Invalid Token Session"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog, opencart2.x

I am adding a custom button to an order list. This button opens up a Jquery UI Dialog box onClick which is interacted with then, upon hitting the "Generate Orders" button, it submits some data to the php controller.

However, whenever I hit the "Generate Orders" button I receive an "Invalid Token Session. Please login again." In the URL, however, it has the same token from the page in which I came from. When I do login, I receive a "non-object" error.

I noticed I receive this same problem when I attempt to move the submit from the onClick="" attribute of my button to a $('button-copy').click(function() { *code here* }

Why is the Invalid Token Session happening and how do I alter the code so that it works properly?

Some explanatory code: It submits the data to the php controller correctly by using the following code with no errors:

```
<button type="button" id="button-copy" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_copy; ?>" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="$('#form-order').attr('action', '<?php echo $copy; ?>').submit();"><i class="fa fa-copy"></i></button>
```

When I move it here, I receive an "Invalid Token Session":

```
$('#button-copy').click(function() {
    $('#form-order').attr('action', '<?php echo $copy; ?>').submit();
});
```

When I try to move it within my Jquery UI Dialog (which does pop up correctly) and I hit the "Generate Orders" button I also receive the "Invalid Token Session":

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#dialog-form').dialog({
        autoOpen: false, 
        height: 400,
        width: 350,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            'Generate Orders': function() {
                $('#form-order').attr('action', '<?php echo $copy; ?>').submit();
            },
             Cancel: function() {
                  $('#dialog-form').dialog('close');
            }
        },
        close: function() {
            $('#dialog-form').dialog('close');
        },
        closeText: "X",
    });
});
$('#button-copy').click(function() {
    $('#dialog-form').dialog('open');

}); 
</script>
```

Again, why is this "Invalid Token Session" happening? Any ideas on how to get around it?

Comment: Hello @Becca. Is this the admin panel right?

Comment: Where are you making the `$data['copy']` in your controller? Can you paste the line?

Comment: $data['copy'] = $this->url->link('sale/subscriptions/copy', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL');